# Pass array object from Ajax to Django Framework

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, django-views

Ajax code

Assume `arry1D` has values `[0,1,2,3,4]`

```
$.ajax({
  url: "{% url 'form_post' %}",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    arry1D: arry1D,
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': tk
  },
  cache:false,

});
```

Below the code of `getModelAttribute()` function in `view.py`

I'm trying to access `arry1D[0]` element but I could not.

```
def getModelAttribute(request, self=None):
    print("In Method")
    if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
        arry1D = request.POST.get('arry1D')
        print(arry1D[0])
        return JsonResponse({'arry1D':arry1D})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get access to your `arry1D` array object you need `getlist()` and not `get()`

change this line

```
arry1D = request.POST.get('arry1D')
```

to

```
arry1D = request.POST.getlist('arry1D')
```

refer to this topic https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist